# I am customising ExoPlayer in my application I want full screen mode like MX Player

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

To enable full screen mode I am using,

```
private void showSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

and to hide using,

```
   private void hideSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

I want full screen mode effect like MX Player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue using above solution and

```
   <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlaybackControlView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I have used `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` only to `PlaybackControlView` not to root view of activity xml file.